# How to say a file is very small?

Tags: word-request, measure-expressions

Is there a way saying a file doesn't have a lot of bytes?

If I want to say: **"The smallest app"**, when small is regarding file size, how would i say that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- The most lightweight app ever created
- The lightest app ever

This is marketing lingo; not technical lingo per se.

Answer (score 0):

The adjective *tiny* is a great, everyday word that you can use to describe something as being very small in size regardless of its nature. You could say, for instance, *a tiny room*, *a tiny car* and, sure enough, even *a tiny file*, *a tiny app* or *a tiny program*. Here are a couple of example sentences:

> It's **a very tiny app** that only requires one megabyte of free disk space on your computer to install it.
>
> A cookie is **a tiny file** with a small piece of information which a website leaves on your computer.

Comment: And would you say tiniest app?

Comment: I think it's absolutely possible to say that: *MailBuddy is the tiniest app ever created for managing your email effectively.* But I don't think that's a very common wording, though.

Answer (score 0):

You could say that the app is

- small **[in terms of](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/in-terms-of-something) file size** (that is, specifying that we're talking about the file size when saying "small"), or
- small **[as measured in](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22as%20measured%20in%22&tbm=bks) bytes** (that is, specifying that we are talking about using bytes as a unit of measurement when saying "small").